# Pass a pointer to dynamically assigned variable to a function to deleting

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

libtestm.dll code

```
#pragma once
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestValue
{
public:
    std::vector<int> v;
    TestValue()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            v.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    ~TestValue()
    {
        std::cout << "Deteled Test Value" << std::endl;
    }
};

EXPORT TestValue *TestReturn()
{
    return new TestValue();
}

EXPORT size_t TestData(TestValue *pt, int **array)
{
    *array = pt->v.data();
    return pt->v.size();
}

EXPORT void TestDelete(TestValue *pt)
{
    if(pt)
    {
        delete pt;
    }
}
```

TestLib.py

```
import os, sys
from ctypes import *
import Libs.Utils as u

__dllname__: str = 'libtestm.dll'

__dllfile__: str = None
__dll__: cdll = None
__dllfile__, __dll__ = u.FindLoadDll(__dllname__, __file__) # get dll from this method

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = __dll__.TestReturn()
    __dll__.TestDelete(v)
```

console output when i run this code

```
Deteled Test Value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\MyProjects\GitRepo\CodePython\Dlls\TestLib.py", line 31, in <module>
    __dll__.TestDelete(v)
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000A20E2490
```

It was difficult to use the c++ standard library with ctypes of python, so I tried to use it by wrapping it in a class. Freeing a pointer to a dynamically allocated variable was successful, but an error occured. Please let me know what am I wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard error of most beginning `ctypes` users.  `ctypes` assumes arguments types if not specified, and that is typically `c_int` or a pointer for arguments, and `c_int` for return types.  Since `TestValue*` is 64-bit, `c_int` for a return value is 32-bit and truncates it.  The solution is to get in the habit of *always* specifying `.argtypes` and `.restype` for each function used:

test.cpp:

```cpp
#pragma once
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestValue {
public:
    std::vector<int> v;
    TestValue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            v.push_back(i);
    }
    ~TestValue() {
        std::cout << "Deleted Test Value" << std::endl;
    }
};

EXPORT TestValue *TestReturn() {
    return new TestValue();
}

EXPORT size_t TestData(TestValue *pt, int **array) {
    *array = pt->v.data();
    return pt->v.size();
}

EXPORT void TestDelete(TestValue *pt) {
    if(pt)
        delete pt;
}
```

test.py:

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.TestReturn.argtypes = ()
dll.TestReturn.restype = c_void_p
dll.TestData.argtypes = c_void_p,POINTER(POINTER(c_int))
dll.TestData.restype = c_size_t
dll.TestDelete.argtypes = c_void_p,
dll.TestDelete.restype = None

v = dll.TestReturn()
data = POINTER(c_int)()
size = dll.TestData(v,byref(data))
print(data[:size])
dll.TestDelete(v)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Deleted Test Value
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Even though I skipped about the 64-bit configuration, thanks even more for the complete explanation.
As you said, I'm a starter to both C++ and Python. I need to study more. Thank you again for the perfect answer.